# How can I make a newArray out of an HTML element?

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to make an array like this:

```js
["name", "email", "phone", "submit"]
```

...out of HTML like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
```

Here's my code:

```js
let textArray = [];
let divText = "";

$("div").each(function () {
  divText = $("div")
    .text()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|[` `])/gi, ``);
});

textArray.push(divText);
```

But the array I'm getting looks like this:

```
["NameEmailPhoneSubmitNameEmailPhone"]
```

...not like this:

```js
["name", "email", "phone", "submit"]
```

Comment: textArrray.push should be in the each loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
let textArray = []
let divText = $("div, button").map((i,x) => x.innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|[` `])/gi, ``)).get();
console.log(divText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
```